# Dynamically setted action attribute of form not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I am setting the action attribute of the Form tag by following line

```
   $("#divIsInternational span").bind('click', function() {
    $('#action').val('bypcgDestination');
    var SelectedItem = $(this).attr("id");
    if (SelectedItem.toString() == "Domestic") {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("domestic selected");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");

        $("#toDefaultPage").attr("action", "home/domestic");
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("international selected");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");

        $("#toDefaultPage").attr("action", "home/international");
    }


    $("#isDomesticInMaster").val(SelectedItem);

    $("#toDefaultPage").submit();

});
```

It works fine in chrome but not in firefox, i am not able to find issue because Firefox console also not showing some error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to share the problem that i face here,actually i am given a id of a hidden field as action.By which i am unable to set the action field of form tag.So problem is hidden field with id = "action".

Answer (score 0):

if the selector `#toDefaultPage` is a form element, then you should be able to use jQuery's built in `.submit()`-function : http://api.jquery.com/submit/